# How to prevent autofill of admin info in create new user form?

Tags: html, google-chrome, yii, autofill

Using [Yii 1.1.12](http://www.yiiframework.com/) php framework although that may not be relevant.  When logged in as the admin user, on my create new user page (an mvc view that I have created), the form autofills with the admin's username and password (at least using when using google chrome because I have saved them for the site).

However the purpose of the form is to create brand new users so it doesn't make sense to auto populate the admin's username and password.  How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('value'=>'', 'placeholder'=>"Username", 'autocomplete'=>"off")); ?>
<?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('value'=>'', 'placeholder'=>"Password", 'autocomplete'=>"off")); ?>
```

Comment: No longer true for Chrome

Comment: Is there any way of achieving this with HTML4?